# how to use alias commands in vhdl

Tags: alias, vhdl

i use alias command in vhdl but had error "Index constraint cannot be applied to already-constrained type vec."

my code is

```
    type vec is array (11 downto 0) of std_logic;
    signal s:vec;
    alias s1:vec (3 downto 0) is s(11 downto 8);
    alias s2:vec (4 downto 0) is s(7 downto  4);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do:

```
signal vec: std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);-- std_logic_vector IS an array of std_logic's
alias s1: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) is vec(3 downto 0);
alias s2: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) is vec(7 downto 0);-- note: Left: #4 = Right: #4
```

Comment: Modelsim error messages of the original code:

    ** Error: test.vhd(13): (vcom-1358) In array constraint at depth 1 the array vec has already been constrained.

    ** Error: test.vhd(14): (vcom-1358) In array constraint at depth 1 the array vec has already been constrained.

    ** Error: test.vhd(13): (vcom-1272) Length of expected is 12; length of slice name is 4.

    ** Error: test.vhd(14): (vcom-1272) Length of expected is 12; length of slice name is 4.